# How to access to relations of a model in activeRecord?

Tags: php, model, yii2, relation

I have a model like bellow:

```
 class Book extends ActiveRecord
   {
        { public function getDomain()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Domain::className(), ['ID' => 'domainID']);
        }

        public function getOwnerPerson()
        {
            return $this->$this->hasOne(Person::className(), ['ID' => 'ownerPersonID']);
        }

        public function getCreatorUser()
        {
            return $this->$this->hasOne(User::className(), ['ID' => 'creatorUserID']);
        }

        public function getUpdaterUser()
        {
            return $this->$this->hasOne(User::className(), ['ID' => 'updaterUserID']);
        }
    }
```

I've created an object from Book model by follow:
`$model=Book::find()->all();`
when I use `$model->domain`, every thing is ok, but when I use `$model->ownerPerson`, it throws an error:
`Object of class backend\models\Book could not be converted to string`

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second $this.

```
return $this->$this->hasOne(Person::className(), ['ID' => 'ownerPersonID']);
to
return $this->hasOne(Person::className(), ['ID' => 'ownerPersonID']);
```